# Dynamic Array and Repeating Values

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, allocation

I am struggling to understand where I am going wrong. My goal is to double the size of an array, and copy the original values twice to the new array. This is currently just printing out 6 zeros. Please help!!

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

void repeatArray(double *&myArray, int size)
{
        double *repeatArray = new double[size * 2]; 

        for(int i =0; i < size; i++)
        {
                 myArray[i] = repeatArray[i]; 
        }

        delete [] myArray;
        myArray = repeatArray;  
}

int main()
{
    double* myArray = new double[3];
    myArray[0] = 1;
    myArray[1] = 2;
    myArray[2] =3;
    repeatArray(myArray, 3);

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        cout << myArray[i] << endl;
    }
    delete []myArray;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `repeatArray()` does not change the value of `size`, so the loop only copies three values.   And it only copies values from `repeatArray` to `myArray`, whereas it needs to copy from `myArray` to `repeatArray`.

Answer (score 1):

`myArray[i] = repeatArray[i];` is wrong. It should be `repeatArray[i] = myArray[i];` in the repeatArray function.

okay I missed the copy over twice part..

```
void repeatArray(double *&myArray, int size)
{
        double *repeatArray = new double[size * 2]; 

        for(int i =0; i < size; i++)
        {
                 repeatArray[i] = myArray[i];
                 repeatArray[i+size] = myArray[i];
        }

        delete [] myArray;
        myArray = repeatArray;  
}
```

This would copy over the values corectly and have it come over twicew

Comment: thank you! now it only prints the first 3 values, and then zero after that. Is my loop incorrect?

Comment: how would i loop through again? I am super confused on how to copy the original values to the new array twice

Comment: @VictoriaKohner-Flangan I didn't read the twice part, please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i =0; i < *size*; i++)
        {
                 myArray[i] = repeatArray[i]; 
        }
```

Your program prints only 3 values, because you did not assign proper values to your new array. The problem is that you loop through the old size, not size * 2.

You might deal with it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size * 2; i++)
{
    // The first part of the array
    if (i < size)
    {
        // Copy values from another array
        repeatArray[i] = myArray[i];
    }
    // The second part of the array
    else
    {
        // Copy valeus from the first part
        repeatArray[i] = myArray[i - size];
    }
}
```

Comment: So I changed it to loop through the new size, and the 4th value is a "3.21143e-322"

Comment: The fourth value is garbage data because your array has a size of 3.

Comment: the 5th and 6th values are 1 and 2, which is not garbage. Why is only the 4th?

Comment: I added a possible solution. When you loop for the first time (iterations below the amount of size) you know that you have to copy them from another array. When you are above it the only thing to do is to copy the value from the element with an index of current iteration - size of the array.